# Java8 Collecting maps

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have this object:

```
public class MenuPriceByDay implements Serializable {

    private BigDecimal avgPrice;
    private BigDecimal minPrice;
    private BigDecimal maxPrice;
    private Date updateDate;

..
}
```

and this other one:

```
public class Statistics {

     double min;
     double max;
     double average;

     public Statistics() {
        super();
     }



    public Statistics(double min, double max, double average) {
        super();
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.average = average;
    }



}
```

and also a list of prices:

```
List<MenuPriceByDay> prices = new ArrayList<MenuPriceByDay>();
```

that I want to convert to a map:

```
Map<LocalDate, Statistics> last30DPerDay =  

        prices
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MenuPriceByDay::getUpdateDate, p -> new Statistics(   p.getAvgPrice().doubleValue(),
                    p.getMaxPrice().doubleValue(),
                    p.getMinPrice().doubleValue())));
```

but I got a compilation problem:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Date,Object> to 
 Map<LocalDate,Statistics>
```

Comment: What if you have 2 price with the same LocalDate. Which statistics should be used then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpdateDate` is of type `Date` and you try to collect as `LocalDate`, so you just need to convert the `Date` to `LocalDate` :

```
Map<LocalDate, Statistics> collect = prices.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.getUpdateDate()
        .toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDate(),
                 p -> new Statistics(p.getAvgPrice().doubleValue(),
                        p.getMaxPrice().doubleValue(),
                        p.getMinPrice().doubleValue())
        ));
```

More details about [Convert Date to LocalDate or LocalDateTime and Back](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime)

Or you can create a method instead like so :

```
public LocalDate convertToLocalDateViaInstant(Date dateToConvert) {
    return dateToConvert.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDate();
}
```

and your code can be :

```
  Map<LocalDate, Statistics> collect = prices.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    m -> this.convertToLocalDateViaInstant(m.getUpdateDate()),
                    p -> new Statistics(p.getAvgPrice().doubleValue(),
                            p.getMaxPrice().doubleValue(),
                            p.getMinPrice().doubleValue())
            ));
```

---

### Better solution

the best solution is Just to change `updateDate` type to `LocalDate` :

```
private LocalDate updateDate;
```

and you can just use your code

Answer (score 2):

Note when you are using [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) you can get `IllegalStateException` if you have duplicate keys.

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to Object.equals(Object)), an IllegalStateException is thrown when the collection operation is performed.

You can use [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) instead. Also there is solution with `groupingBy`, and in this case you should decide which statistic has to be used when duplicating key:

```
Map<LocalDate, Optional<Statistics>> map = prices.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(p -> p.getUpdateDate()
                            .toInstant()
                            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                            .toLocalDate(),
                    mapping(p-> new Statistics(
                            p.getMinPrice().doubleValue(),
                            p.getAvgPrice().doubleValue(),
                            p.getMaxPrice().doubleValue()),
                            reducing((s1, s2) -> ???)      // here
```